# Is it possible to do live streaming with FFmpeg in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, live

I know its possible for FFmpeg to render from the webcam to SWF and FLV. But the problem is the SWF file can only be read via AS2 and FLV seems to only be loading a static frame from my Flash Player.

Is there a way for FFmpeg to render a AVM3 SWF or a stream-able FLV?

Comment: Is an RTMP server such as Red5 an option for you?  http://osflash.org/red5

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I don't think I need it realtime. 

Anyway I found there's an extra option to input for FFServer to render as AVM2 using the following command.

ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf avm2 test.swf